# /etc/crypttab timeout option

Tags: encryption, luks

I have created an encrypted flash drive named 'LUKSFlash'. I have tested with the following:

```
    $ sudo cryptdisks_start LUKSFlash
```

/dev/mapper/LUKSFlash now exists

```
    $ sudo cryptdisks_stop LUKSFlash
```

/dev/mapper/LUKSFlash now gone.

All works as expected so far.

Here's the entry in /etc/crypttab:

```
    LUKSFlash UUID=6f86be79-723d-4ce5-9ce1-047960b649c1 none luks,timeout=10
```

The issue:
When booting the system with flash drive plugged in, I get a prompt to enter password. However the prompt dissapears so quickly it does not give me time to actually enter in a password. I have used the 'timeout' option in crypttab however that option seems to be ignored at bootup.

Before anyone asks: Yes, I do want to be prompted for a password and do not want to use a key.

12.04 LTS

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:
There must be a corresponding entry in /etc/fstab in order for this to work properly.

The timeout=10 option in 12.04 LTS appears to b unsupported